# Change vertical line spacing for only one paragraph

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

Is there a way to change the vertical spacing between lines for only one paragraph? Suppose, for example, I want everything in my document to be single-spaced, except for one paragraph that I want to be double spaced (or custom spaced to any length in general). Are there any simple suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the adjustment to the line spacing inside a group (meaning it'll reset afterward). You have to make sure that there's an empty line before closing the group, or an explicit `\par` to ensure that the paragraph building feature can be performed using the newly-specified parameters. So something like

```
% ...stuff before

\begingroup
\setstretch{1.5}% Adjust line spacing
% ...your paragraph here
\par
\endgroup

% ...more stuff here
```

But [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace) conveniently provides the `spacing` environment that does all that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{spacing}{1.5}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{spacing}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```